# How can I listen for when the screen insets change?

Tags: java, swing

I'm developing an application that sets its size to fit the screen's bounds (taking into account the screen's insets). However if the insets change, for example when I auto-hide my taskbar when the application is already visible, the size of the window remains the same. Is it possible to listen for when those insets might change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for the taskbar to be hidden, your application must lose focus, right? So you could use a WindowFocusListener and just get the screen insets again on focus gained.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and it works very well, however it only resizes to the correct bounds when the window regains focus (obviously). Maybe the OS does the resizing of the windows? In that case this is the best answer possible.